# undefined のエラー表示について

Tags: javascript

現在todoリストの作成を行っているのですが、作成したリストをコンソールに呼び出す段階で"lists is not defined"のエラー表示が出てきてしまいデータの取得ができません。varを用いてlistsと変数宣言しているのですがなぜエラー表示が出るのでしょうか。解決法を教えていただきたいです。

todoリストの作成は YouTubeの ”JavaScriptの「基礎」が1時間で分かる「超」入門講座【初心者向け】 だれでもエンジニア / 山浦清透” に沿って行っています。
よろしくお願いします。
[image: コンソール画面]　
[image: html]
[image: index.js]

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ToDo List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <h1>ToDo List</h1>
    <style>
            h1{text-align:center; color:rgba(195, 64, 16, 0.83); font-family:fantasy; font-size:80px;}
    </style>
    <form id="form" name="form">
        <input id="input" placeholder="Things to do" type="text">
    </form>
    <style>
              #form{text-align: center;}
    </style>
    <ul class="list-group text-secondary" id="ul"></ul>
    <script src="index.js">
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    add();
});
function add() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = input.value;
    li.classList.add("list-group-item");
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
　  saveData();
 }
}　　
function saveData(){var lists=
document.querySelectorAll("li");
 console.log(lists);
}
```

Comment: いただいたソースコードではsyntaxエラーは出るものの、それを解消する（`function saveData()`の前の`{`を消す）と問題なく動くようです。質問にあるようなエラーは出てきません。もう一度ソースコードを見直すか正しくコピペしてみてください

Comment: こちらに添付したコードをコピペして試しましたがやはりエラー表示がでてきます。実際の画面を画像添付しましたので確認していただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: console.log(lists);のコンソールは正しく出ているようです。画像を見るとdebuggerのエラーのようです。debuggerに何か仕込んでいませんか？ブラウザを変えてみるとおそらく正しく動くと思います。

Comment: `lists` は `saveData()` 関数のローカル変数ですので、コンソール(global scope)からは参照できません。

Comment: ＠keitaro_so firefoxで開いているのですがエクスプローラーを使うとページが表示されなくなってしまいます。どちらのブラウザが有効なのでしょうか...

Comment: ＠metropolis youtubeを見る限りこの方はこの方法でコンソールにlistsの結果を表示しているようなのですが何が違うのでしょうか。

Comment: @Suzu  `form` や `url` 変数を定義している部分(ソースコードの最初の部分)が global scope になります。そこで `var lists;` としておいて、`saveData()` 内で `lists =
document.querySelectorAll("li");` とします(`var` を付けません)。この様にすることで `lists` をコンソールの REPL から参照する事ができる様になります。

Comment: ＠keitaro_so ＠metropolis コンソール内にvar listsのソースコードをコピペすることでコンソール内にlistsの参照が可能になりました。ありがとうございました‼